# Поддержка двух веток проекта

Tags: git, контроль-версий, svn

Есть проект, который велся предыдущим программистом без всяких систем контроля версии. Теперь этот проект передают мне для масштабного рефакторинга. В то же время текущую поддержку этого проекта и исправлением найденных багов будет заниматься предыдущий программист.

Если повезет, то после каждого найденного бага я буду получать новый комплект исходников. Если не повезет - то я его буду получать просто каждую неделю две.

Вопрос: как бы мне вливать полученные изменения в мою ветку проекта?

Была идея сделать две ветки `old` и `new`. Самому вести ветку `new`, а полученные исходники вливать в ветку `old`. Потом формировать diff между двумя коммитами в `old` и заливать этот `diff` в `new`. Но если я правильно понимаю, как только изменится нумерация строк в одной из веток, то diff перестанет накатываться. Или я ошибаюсь?

В общем, хочу узнать, как эту задачу можно решить? В идеале на svn. Если нет, то могу развернуть любую другую систему контроля версий.

Comment: А можно спросить, почему у Вас предпочтение отдаётся svn? Просто в терминах git вроде задача не особо сложная, более того, можно грубо говоря сделать работу программиста совершенно обезьяньей - вы ему создаёте ветку, и единственный способ прислать Вам "комплект исходников" - сделать PULL REQUEST. И никаких diff'ов!

Comment: Мерджи (не важно в какой VCS) перестанут работать, как только у вас код достаточно существенно разбежится (особенно быстро это произойдет, если вы будете масштабно рефакторить имена и расположения классов, менять структуру). Вы в процессе рефакторинга наплодите кучу своих багов, не переживайте. Подход сильно зависит от устройства проекта и глубины рефакторинга. Из тех случаев, что были в моей практике - либо не делить проект, а оборачивать его тестами и рефакторить "как есть" по кускам; либо писать новый проект "сбоку"  посматривая на старый лишь для справки.

Comment: @S.H. svn используется исторически. Но я написал, что могу развернуть любую систему, если это будет проще. pull request он делать не будет. Я буду получать от него zip архив, разворачивать и сам коммитить в нужную ветку. Распишите как задача решается в git

Comment: @Kromster я понимаю, что мерджи когда-то перестанут работать, но они будут работать первое время. Проект огромен и тянется с конца 90-х, переписывать с нуля, по моим прикидкам будет сильно сложнее. поэтому у меня задача номер раз просто выкинуть устаревшие куски

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, Вам в комментариях сделали довольно много полезных замечаний.

Я бы присоединился к замечанию "обложить весь код тестами, как селедку майонезом".

Я в своё время столкнулся с тем, что в SVN пререстали мержиться ветки в моём проекте (немного, около 100 тысяч строк), и именно это было последней каплей для перехода на git (и это было уже лет семь назад).

Как бы я решал задачу в git:

1. Вы можете импортировать туда историю из svn. Я при переезде так и сделал. Руководств на эту тему - масса, и, кажется, github даже поддерживает импорт таких репозиториев. Но если до сих пор vcs не использовалась - Вам это не актуально.
2. Когда у Вас есть "текущий мастер" - то вы работаете в двух направлениях:

- сами создаётё ветку под конкретный рефакторинг, потм вливаете её в мастер
- когад Вам присылают архив - вы опять таки, создаёте ветку, и накатываете на неё архив. А вотом вливаете в мастер. (ну, по современной политкорректной терминологии -в мейн, но это ничего не меняет)

Остальное - происходит естественным образом при вливании веток обратно в мастер: в большинстве случаев они авто-смерджатся, иногда - когад будет возникать конфликт - надо будет смотреть глазами и праввить исходники перед мержем.

Но общее ощущение от способности гита мержить - очень хорошее.

Comment: Все создания веток происходят из текущего мастера?

Comment: Вот это очень хороший вопрос... Если говорить о Вашей работе - вы всё время можете работать с мастером. Ну, грубо говоря, отрефакторили - влили, если потом что то другое рефакторите - в исходниках уже есть предыдущий рефакторинг. А вот если у Вас "внешний" программист, колторый присылает zip-ы -  работает с "замороженной" копией проекта - ВОЗМОЖНО, лучше сразу создать "замороженную" ветку, из неё создавать все ветки под каждый его zip-архив, а вливать их - однорвеменно и в мастер, ив  "замороженную" ветку. Тогда у вас в замороженной ветке код будет "как у него", в мастере - самый свежий

Comment: не за что, но я подумал - важно еще и использовать ту систему, в которой у Вас есть опыт... первые мои эксперименты с git были довольно натужными, и только потом появилась какая то легкость в пальцах. а по сути: отличной особенностью git является возможность делать PR в две (или более) веток